# Filtering API data and rendering items upon a button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I fetch data from an API that returns an array of objects each representing a movie, similar to this:

[{ "name": "The Matrix", "img": "http://...", "description": "Lorem ipsum...", "first_aired": "1999" }, ...]

What I want is:

1. Render all movies as cards on initial loading of the app
2. Have a button that, upon clicking it, would filter and only show those movies that are aired before year 2013.

Pasting below what I've implemented so far, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing it. I.e. instead of the ternary operator, is there a way of simply having `<CardList items={movies} />` and passing either ALL movies or FILTERED (a subset) movies, as props, depending if the button is toggled or not.

I tried doing that inside the `handleToggle` handler with `if (toggle) {}` type of logic that worked up to a point that clicking the button would filter and thus render all movies aired before 2013 but clicking it again wouldn't update the `movies` state variable back to ALL movies and render them, accordingly.

Inside the `CardList` component there's also a `Card` component, if that helps. And inside the `CardList` component I'm using the `map` function to iterate over the `movies`/`filteredMovies` props to render the `Card` component(s).

```js
function App() {
   const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
   const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);
 
   useEffect(() => {
     const getData = fetch('https://api.com/movies')
     .then(data => data.json())
     .then(items => setMovies(items))
   }, [])

const filteredMovies = movies.filter(item => item.first_aired <= 2013);

const handleToggle = () => setToggle(!toggle)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleToggle}>{toggle ? "Only show movies aired ≤ 2013" : "Show all movies"}</button>
      {toggle ? <CardList items={movies} /> : <CardList items={filteredMovies} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function App() {
   const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
   const [moviesBackup, setMoviesBackup] = useState([]);
   const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);
 
   useEffect(() => {
     const getData = fetch('https://api.com/movies')
     .then(data => data.json())
     .then(items => {setMovies(items), setMoviesBackup(items)})
   }, [])

const filteredMovies = movies.filter(item => item.first_aired <= 2013);

const handleToggle = () => {
  setToggle(!toggle);
  //Permit this condition if i am wrong according to button state
  if(toggle === true){
    setMovies(filteredMovies)
  }else{
    setMovies(moviesBackup)
  }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleToggle}>{toggle ? "Only show movies aired ≤ 2013" : "Show all movies"}</button>
        <CardList items={movies} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually defeating the idea of React here. React way would be replace

```
{toggle ? <CardList items={movies} /> : <CardList items={filteredMovies} />}
```

with just `<CardList items={filteredMovies} />` where filteredMovies is a hook and then just mutate `filteredMovies` with `setFiteredMovies()`. React will update the UI automatically.